# Does an iOS app automatically check for new versions?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

Do I need to implement functionality within my app to check the store for newer versions, or is this done for you automatically? If I do need to do this, how would I go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its done automatically by the app store. When the user enters to the App Store on his iPhone and theres a new version the "Updates" count will increase and notify the user.

Some like posting this stuff as Push notifications for the user, but many users don't appreciate it much :)

Answer (score 0):

This is all handled by the App Store. You don't need this.

Comment: In some situations, you might want it. If you had to change the APIs the app uses, or if you found a bug that allows people to cheat in multiplayer, etc.